# Count double values in array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, laravel-4

I have this array at this moment and i need to count how many times 1 is in this array. I have no clue how to do this. 
I tried `array_count_values()`

but that gives the following error `array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!`

How can i do this?

Part of my array:

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/N1DwqZyD)

Comment: your array is multidimensional array_count_values() only work for simple(index or associative) array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code count all "1" values in your stdClass

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $v) {
        if ('1' === $v) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($count);
```

Answer (score 1):

@pascal zoet In your multidimensional array case array_count_values() will not work because it works for  simple(index or associative) array

do it with simple loop and condition like below:

```
<?php
 $count = 0;
 foreach($yourArray as $value){
    if($value["qlval"] == "1"){
        $count++;
    }
 }
 echo "I count is: " . $count;
```